# How to repeat an image in horizontal axis in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to repeat an image in horizontal axis and with Positioned widget move the image to  the left or right side. I tried it with Image.network and Image.asset and both don't work.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: -100,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: 1500,
              child: Image.network(
                'http://www.testomic.com/public/codepen-assets/img/paralax/foreground.png',
                repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatX,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

What's wrong with my code! Thank you in advance.

Comment: It works just fine, you image is too wide to be repeated given the screen size. Check this [codepen[(https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/XWXjjMW) where it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Thanks a lot. You saved my life!